# NSIS close process by glob

Tags: process, glob, nsis

I have a code for nsis which show you a message if specified process is run

```
    nsProcess::_FindProcess "NCover.exe"
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 = 0
        ifSilent +1 +3
    SetErrorLevel 3
    Abort
        MessageBox MB_OK "Process NCover is running please close."
        Goto Recheck
    ${EndIf}
```

But it's not work with a glob pattern like "*.res". What can i use to do this with glob?

Comment: `*.res` is a glob pattern, not a regex.

Comment: Have you looked at the Locked List plug-in?

Comment: @greybeard oops))))

Comment: @Anders it's good, but dont show all processes (dont know why)